# My c-string copy function is corrupting the stack of other variables

Tags: c++

This function worked fine in another program, but in some cases it causes a runtime error saying that the stack around some variable, sometimes one that wasn't even sent into the function, was corrupted.

```
char *strCpy(char *dest, const char *source) {      // copy cstring
    char *origin = dest;                            // non iterated address
    while (*source || *dest) {
        *dest = *source;
        dest++;
        source++;
    }
    return origin;
}
```

implementation of the function:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Will it crash?\n";
    char temp[255];
    char b[255];
    std::cin >> temp;
    strCpy(b, temp);
    std::cout << b;
    std::cout << "end\n";
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, temp is corrupted, but not necessarily because it was passed into the function. I'm having trouble hunting down the issue beyond this.

The reason I wrote my own copy function is because of restrictions on the project. I am also not allowed to use `[]` to index arrays

Comment: You're not allowed to read from `dest` in strcpy, only write to it (and pray it's big enough).

Comment: Get rid of `|| *dest` in your condition of your while loop.

Comment: Not allowed to index arrays? What world is this.

Comment: @drescherjm If I get rid of `|| *dest` and whatever dest was before being overwritten by the copy is shorter than the back half of the cstring will still be there.  For example, in `strCpy("wxyz","abc")`, wxyz will become abcz instead of the desired abc.

Comment: @Carl The world of college computer science class

Comment: You need to also copy the `\0` to the end of `dest`.

Answer (score 4):

Your logic in the loop condition is flawed and will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The contents of the destination is *uninitialized* and therefore *indeterminate*. You should not check the destination at all in your condition, only the source:

```
while (*source) { ... }
```

And of course, you need to add the terminator to the destination. This can simply be done after the loop like

```
*dest = '\0';
```

Comment: You should also mention `strncopy`, just for completeness and for people coming here to copy this copy function. *meta-copy  :S*

Comment: I guess that explains why it worked in my other program, the destination was always defined before `strCpy` was called to overwrite it.

Comment: I'm now going back into the old programs I wrote and they're now also corrupting stacks. These programs were fully functional before, I'm not sure how this can happen. Even a version with a completely different strCpy function is causing the same error. Is anyone else able to replicate this?

Comment: This is UB = undefined behaviour at its best. It may work, it may fail, it may work again ... Just fix it.

Comment: Removing `|| *dest` did not stop the errors and now when it does work it stopped writing over the remainder of dest, leaving the back half of a word when copying from a smaller word.

Comment: @griffin175 Do you remember to terminate the destination string?

Comment: ur source is too long . let me sleep and the code use other people a lot of hours